# What are plausible reasons provision a container app in Azure fails with "Conflict", and why are there no logs written to the analytics workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

The exact status message provisioning fails with is:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "90008",
        "message": "Failed to provision revision for container app '***********'. Error details: Operation expired."
    }
}
```

When I try to get data from log analytics with the command:

```
az monitor log-analytics query --workspace **************** --analytics-query "ContainerAppConsoleLogs_CL | where ContainerAppName_s == '******' | project ContainerAppName_s, Log_s, TimeGenerated"
```

I get => `BadArgumentError: The request had some invalid properties`
This is probably related to the fact that no custom table has been created in the custom logs of the log analytics workspace (assumption).

The deployment is automated using a bicep script. I ran the command in debug mode to get the most output, but it does not give much additional useful information:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group rg-radix-samples-shop --template-file .\main.bicep --debug
```

The most useful part is, which might give insiders some extra information:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/arm.py", 
line 109, in handle_template_based_exception        
AttributeError: 'OperationFailed' object has no attribute 'error'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 657, in execute
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 712, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/arm.py", 
line 112, in handle_template_based_exception        
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/arm.py", 
line 104, in raise_subdivision_deployment_error     
azure.cli.core.azclierror.DeploymentError: {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n  
  \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n        \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\",\r\n    
    \"details\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"code\": \"Conflict\",\r\n            \"message\": \"{\\r\\n  \\\"status\\\": \\\"Failed\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": {\\r\\n    \\\"code\\\": \\\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"message\\\": \\\"The 
resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"details\\\": [\\r\\n      {\\r\\n        \\\"code\\\": \\\"90008\\\",\\r\\n        \\\"message\\\": \\\"Failed to provision revision for container app '************'. Error details: Operation expired.\\\"\\r\\n  
    }\\r\\n    ]\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}
```

So I basically got 2 questions:

- What could be causing the provisioning to fail?
- Why are there no logs written to my analytics workspace (or anywhere) so that I can diagnose what is going on?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you gone to the `Deployments` blade for the resource group containing the container app? Are there any failed deployments?

Comment: Yes, that is where the first error message is copied from

Comment: Another symptom I noticed is that the container is actually stuck in the provisioning state

Comment: I'm assuming the impossibility to view basic logs is by design.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to have changed (maybe an improvement?). The error code was still the same but the message had some more info, namely that it was not able to pull the docker image. In the end, it was the case that the docker image name had a typo (figures).

Comment: Did you find the error with additional info in the deployment blade of the resource group? Having the same issue at the moment with the deployment of a custom container but having a hard time pinpointing what's actually failing the deployment